# Resuming a previous fragment onBackPressed()?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I have a `HomeFragment` that has a button, which when clicked calls the following:

```
Fragment frag = new CustFragment();
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.home_container, frag).commit();
```

Then in my `FragmentActivity` which is the fragments mentioned above, I have:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    super.onBackPressed();

}
```

That's what I've tried, but if I'm on the `frag` fragment and I press the back button, it doesn't go back to the last fragment (the `HomeFragment`). Instead, it attempts to go back to the last Activity, but since there is none (i.e. the previous activity had `finish()` invoked on it), it just goes to the Android Home Screen.

What am I doing wrong?

PS: If I'm being unclear, just comment below and i'll try to clarify.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Change

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() 
{
   getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
   super.onBackPressed();
}
```

to

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() 
{
  if(getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0)
    getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
  else
   super.onBackPressed();
}
```

and

```
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.home_container, frag).commit();
```

to

```
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.home_container, frag).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

Comment: OnBackPressed is not needed if you use addToBackStack

Comment: @KlassenK If he doesn't do that `super.onBackPressed();` will directly exit the `Activity`

Comment: Try to add "addToBackStack(null)" to your transaction like I linked in my answer and remove onBackPressed completely.

Answer (score 3):

Add your fragment to back stack using `addToBackStack(null)` like..

```
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.home_container, frag).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

Answer (score 1):

beginTransaction creates a new FragmentTransaction. It has a method [addToBackstack](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#addToBackStack%28java.lang.String%29). If you call it before you commit your transaction you can remove your overridden onBackPressed completely. [Reference](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Transactions)

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
```

and no need to take care of `onBackPressed()`.

BTW in your `onBackPressed()` `super.onBackPressed()` means you are actually changing nothing.

It should have been something like:

```
if(currentFragmentIsCustFragment){
   getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
}else{
   super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Comment: Ohh okay. Wait, how come I don't have to take care of `onBackPressed`? Will it pop off the stack automatically if I press the back button without me having to implement it?

Comment: Yeah, that is taken care by `fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);`